# show multi select id by js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need show selection id by js, by this code only show 1 and first select id

my code is this html and javascript

```
<tr>
<td>
  <select name="jens_id[]" id="jens_id" required="" >
    <option ></option>
    <option >1</option>
    <option >2</option>
  </select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
  <select name="jens_id[]" id="jens_id" required="" >
    <option ></option>
    <option >1</option>
    <option >2</option>
  </select>
</td>
</tr>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#jens_id').change(function(){
        statteId = $("#jens_id").val()
        alert(statteId);
    });
}); 
</script>
```

can help for edit script

Comment: You have used the `id="jens_id"` for both the `select`.

Comment: ID should be unique.. use class and use **this** context

Comment: also use <option val='1' >1</option>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` attribute should be unique within the page otherwise only the first one gets selected(using id selector), for a group of elements use a common class instead and within the change event handler use `this` to refer the clicked element.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="jens_id[]" class="jens_id" required="">
    <option ></option>
    <option >1</option>
    <option >2</option>
  </select>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="jens_id[]" class="jens_id" required="">
    <option ></option>
    <option >1</option>
    <option >2</option>
  </select>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // or use attribute equals selector
    // $('[name="jens_id[]"]')
    $('.jens_id').change(function() {
      statteId = $(this).val(); // or this.value
      console.log(statteId);
      // get the td and update with value
      $(this).parent().next().text(statteId);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks 1 ask i need show this id in new <td> no alert can help this

Comment: You are right when you state that ids should be unique, but even if there is an id used at multiple tags, $("[id=" + yourid + "]") will select them all, only the id selector of # stops at the first finding.

Comment: @LajosArpad : I know that, but it's a bad practice :)

Comment: @PranavCBalan I fully agree with you, but this fact must be mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `each()` function of jquery .And change the selector with `Tagname` or `ClassName` instead of `id` .Id is a unique for full document

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).val())
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
    <select name="jens_id[]" id="jens_id" required="">
    <option ></option>
    <option selected>1</option>
    <option >2</option>
  </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <select name="jens_id[]" id="jens_id" required="">
    <option ></option>
    <option >1</option>
    <option selected>2</option>
  </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.jens_id').change(function() {
    statteId = $('option:selected', this).text()
    alert(statteId);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="jens_id[]" class="jens_id" required="">
    <option ></option>
    <option >1</option>
    <option >2</option>
  </select>

<select name="jens_id[]" class="jens_id" required="">
    <option ></option>
    <option >3</option>
    <option >4</option>
  </select>
```

1. ID should be unique, use class and use this context to tell the current changed select

Comment: you dont have value in html mark up. you can change it in your code accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You are already aware now that id of the element on page should be unique.

When you have multiple elements with same id then `id(#)` selector returns the first matched element. So as mentioned in other answers **you should use class** if possible.

By any reason if you can't use the class and want to find with id then you can use it like `$('select#jens_id')` or `$('[id="jens_id"]')` and to get the selected option use context to `this` which will find the selected option for changed select element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('select#jens_id').change(function() {
      alert($(this).find('option:selected').text());
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="jens_id[]" id="jens_id" required="">
    <option ></option>
    <option >1</option>
    <option >2</option>
  </select>

<select name="jens_id[]" id="jens_id" required="">
    <option ></option>
    <option >3</option>
    <option >4</option>
  </select>
```

Add `multiple` attribute to select if multiple values needs to be selected.