# show select in new td by js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need show selection id by js in class="contentsr" , this code show all in class="contentsr" we need  show first select in first class="contentsr" and second select in second class="contentsr"

my code is this html and javascript

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
 <select name="jens_id[]" class="jens_id" required="">
<option ></option>
<option >1</option>
<option >2</option>
</select><span class="contentsr" ></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="jens_id[]" class="jens_id" required="">
<option ></option>
<option >1</option>
<option >2</option>
</select><span class="contentsr" ></span> </td>
</tr>
</table>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.jens_id').change(function() {
 statteId = $(this).val(); // or this.value
$('.contentsr').text(statteId).val();
 });
 });
```

Comment: `statteId` should be `var  statteId` And `$('.contentsr').text(statteId).val();` to `$('.contentsr').text(statteId);` And Options Should hold some values like `<option value="Select Me" >Select Me</option><option value="1" >1</option>` etc.

Comment: what's the relation to php? There's no code to support the tag.

Comment: didn't you post this already and got an answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44798742/show-multi-select-id-by-js

Comment: use siblings in your code . `$(this).siblings('.contentsr').text(statteId).val();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `next()` for pick only next `<span>` and `html()` to write on `<span>`

**Change:  `$(this).next('.contentsr').html(statteId);`**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.jens_id').change(function() {
 statteId = $(this).val(); // or this.value
$(this).next('.contentsr').html(statteId);
 });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="jens_id[]" class="jens_id" required="">
<option ></option>
<option >1</option>
<option >2</option>
</select>
<span class="contentsr" ></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="jens_id[]" class="jens_id" required="">
<option ></option>
<option >1</option>
<option >2</option>
</select><span class="contentsr" ></span> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

`statteId` should be `var statteId` And `$('.contentsr').text(statteId).val();` to `$('.contentsr').text(statteId);` And `Options` Should hold some values like `<option value="Select Me" >Select Me</option><option value="1" >1</option>` etc.

Your Complete code should be

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="jens_id[]" class="jens_id" required="">
                <option value="Select Me">Select Me</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
            <span class="contentsr" ></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="jens_id[]" class="jens_id" required="">
                <option value="Select Me">Select Me</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
            <span class="contentsr" ></span> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.jens_id').change(function() {
        var statteId = $(this).val(); // or this.value
        $(this).closest('.contentsr').text(statteId);
     });
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: hi thanks Which code can show by ajax post  $(document).ready(function() {
$('.jens_id').change(function() {      
 statteId = $(this).val(); // or this.value
 $.post('.mojodi_test.php', {id:statteId},
   function(results){
  $(this).closest('.contentsr').text(results);
     })
 });
 });

Answer (score 0):

Your class is next to your select element so you can use `next()` to get next span of selected element

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.jens_id').change(function() {      
 statteId = $(this).val(); // or this.value
 $(this).next().text(statteId);

 });
 });
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
 <select name="jens_id[]" class="jens_id" required="">
<option ></option>
<option >1</option>
<option >2</option>
</select><span class="contentsr" ></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="jens_id[]" class="jens_id" required="">
<option ></option>
<option >1</option>
<option >2</option>
</select><span class="contentsr" ></span> </td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.jens_id').change(function() {      
 statteId = $(this).val(); // or this.value
 $(this).next().text(statteId);

 });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix you jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.jens_id').change(function () {
        var statteId = $(this).val(); // or this.value
        $(this).next('.contentsr').text(statteId);
    });
});
```

Comment: that would change all .contentsr elements

Comment: This one is not correct because its change all span text.

Comment: I have corrected that now

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.jens_id').on('change', function(){
    $(this).next('.contentsr').text($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
$(this).closest($(this)).nextAll('.contentsr').html(statteId);
```

insted of

```
$('.contentsr').text(statteId).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you can use the jquery siblings method.

`$(this).siblings('.contentsr').text(statteId).val();`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to get next sibling `.contentsr` span node

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.jens_id').change(function() {
    statteId = $(this).val(); // or this.value
    $(this).next(".contentsr").text($(this).val())
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="jens_id[]" class="jens_id" required="">
<option ></option>
<option >1</option>
<option >2</option>
</select> &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="contentsr"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="jens_id[]" class="jens_id" required="">
<option ></option>
<option >1</option>
<option >2</option>
</select> &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="contentsr"></span> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```